# How to make "small multiples" (map) chart in Altair

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, geopandas, altair

I'm trying to make a small multiples map chart; something like this

[image: small multiples map]

with GeoPandas and Altair. My dataset has the following fields:

- `weekNumber`
- `percentageDiff`
- `geometry`

I want to create a map for each `weekNumber` showing the values in the `percentageDiff` column.

I've managed to make multiple maps on one row, but not in a grid like this one. Here's my code for the maps on one row:

```
charts = []
for x in range(12):
    chart = alt.Chart(ntaGeoData[ntaGeoData.weekNumber == x]).mark_geoshape().encode(
        color=alt.Color(
            'percentageDiff:Q',
            scale=alt.Scale(scheme='redblue',domain=(-1,1)))
    ).properties(
        width=200,
        height=200
    )
    charts.append(chart)

alt.hconcat(*charts)
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

The actual data looks like this:

```
geometry    weekNumber  citiStartDiff   NTAName
0   POLYGON ((-73.99236 40.68969, -73.99436 40.690...   0   -0.319463   Brooklyn Heights-Cobble Hill
1   POLYGON ((-73.99236 40.68969, -73.99436 40.690...   1   0.232122    Brooklyn Heights-Cobble Hill
2   POLYGON ((-73.99236 40.68969, -73.99436 40.690...   2   0.101468    Brooklyn Heights-Cobble Hill
3   POLYGON ((-73.99236 40.68969, -73.99436 40.690...   3   0.191144    Brooklyn Heights-Cobble Hill
4   POLYGON ((-73.99236 40.68969, -73.99436 40.690...   4   0.378864    Brooklyn Heights-Cobble Hill
... ... ... ... ...
6147    MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.86523 40.57046, -73.86454 ...   4   2.520000    park-cemetery-etc-Queens
6148    MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.86523 40.57046, -73.86454 ...   5   0.030769    park-cemetery-etc-Queens
6149    MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.86523 40.57046, -73.86454 ...   6   -0.015625   park-cemetery-etc-Queens
6150    MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.86523 40.57046, -73.86454 ...   7   1.150000    park-cemetery-etc-Queens
6151    MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.86523 40.57046, -73.86454 ...   8   0.509804    park-cemetery-etc-Queens
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [wrapped facet](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/us_population_over_time_facet.html). It would look something like this:

```py
alt.Chart(ntaGeoData).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color=alt.Color(
        'percentageDiff:Q',
        scale=alt.Scale(scheme='redblue',domain=(-1,1))),
    facet=alt.Facet('weekNumber:O', columns=4)
).properties(
    width=200,
    height=200
)
```

Unfortunately, due to a [bug](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2369) in Vega-Lite, this kind of faceting does not work for geographic visualization. As a workaround, you can manually filter the data in pandas, and create a small multiples chart via concatenation. For example:

```python
alt.concat(*(
    alt.Chart(ntaGeoData[ntaGeoData.weekNumber == weekNumber]).mark_geoshape().encode(
      color='citiStartDiff:Q',
    ).properties(
      width=200, height=200
    )
    for weekNumber in range(8)
  ), columns=4
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work to create the grid, but no data shows up. Any ideas why? @jakevdp

Comment: Without seeing your data it's hard to guess.

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample of the exact data. I can also send you the file if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but a partial string representation of the data is not all that helpful. I'm not certain why it doesn't work, and can't investigate without the ability to run the code. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, if this helps, here's the data file: https://github.com/juanfrans/data-sample